# How to hyperlink a specific page of .docx or .pdf file in powerpoint slides

Tags: hyperlink, powerpoint

I want to hyperlink a specific page (say page-12) of .docx or .pdf file in powerpoint slide.  I can add the hyperlink which takes me to that specific file.  But when I add `#page=12` at the end of linked path, it only takes me to its first page.

Can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

If you include some unique text, say "intro" in the Word doc, you can do this:

C:\path\to\whatever.docx#intro

The link will open the DOC and take you to the first instance of the #text, in this case, intro.

So to link to Page 4, add "page4" to the end of a paragraph at the beginning of a section that you want to link to, set it to white and add #page4 to the end of your link in PPT.

It's been a while since I tried to link to pages in PDFs, but at the time, the only way to do it was to put the PDF on a web server and use the URL + #page=x syntax you've mentioned already. I've just done a bit of searching and everything I've found suggests that this is still the case.

Comment: I'll try this and revert.  Thanks